# Free SMTP server with TLS support

Tags: smtp, tls

I'm looking for a free SMTP server with TLS support for testing. I tried using Gmail, but my account got disabled the moment I tried sending an email from a Python script.

Comment: Did you try to bulk-mail, or anything resembling spam? I use my Gmail account occasionally from a PHP script and have not experienced any blockages.

Comment: Nope, just one sender.

Comment: Are you looking for a program or a hosted service?

Comment: Which Operating System are you using?  (Add that answer to your question and I'll upvote your question.)  _P.S.: I provided an answer that applies to MS-Windows just in case that's the OS you're using._

Comment: Thank you so much, Randolf. It worked like a charm. I would have have liked a Linux software, but Windows is just fine.

Comment: @artknish:  You're welcome (and thanks for the update).  This software should work on Linux just fine under WINE, especially because it stores all the configuration information in text files (no Windows Registry settings that I'm aware of anyway).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the Windows Operating System (the question doesn't specify which OS is being used), then the Mercury Mail Server by David Harris should meet your needs:

> Mercury Mail Server by David Harris
>   http://www.pmail.com/overviews/ovw_mercury.htm

[image]

Comment: +1 for courier. Its underrated, and a snap to administer

Answer (score 1):

That would be most of them. [courier](http://www.courier-mta.org/couriertls.html), [exim](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-3.20/doc/html/spec_38.html), sendmail, etc.